# Installation of joomla in a url with subdirectory

Tags: php, joomla

I have a website with a url where the /var/www is reached to the address http://www.example.com/meter/

I created a folder called graph and unpacked all joomla files so in /var/www/graph/ are all joomla files.

So if I try to access joomla installation, I go to http://www.example.com/meter/graph/installation/index.php

Then nothing appears correctly and when I checked the source, it seems because it thinks that everything is in http://www.example.com/graph/ forgetting about the meter after example.com

Thanks if you can help,

John.

Comment: So what does the "http://www.example.com/graph/" show ?

Comment: it shows the page but all the links are going to the website without eh meter subdirectory. In fact there are many servers with apache and the access to one server is done through this directory like meter which is not a real directory on the server.

Comment: are you aware of what makes your default website be loaded at the meter directory ?

Comment: no, I got access to a webserver from a farm of server and I know that I named it meter so now I can access it through example.com/meter. If I called it test, I would have accessed it through example.com.test/

Comment: Not sure I can understand the configuration you are on. Why don't you ask the server administrator or hosting provider (whatever it is) ?

Comment: Do you have htaccess file in your grap folder? If yes check RewriteBase parameter.